# Row height don't include scrollviewer ability

Tags: wpf

I'm currently creating a new WPF window which look like this :
[image: Main window]

The part starting with "Filter and with the array is define like this :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{Binding FilterVisibility}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Text="{Binding Source={x:Static dictionnaries:MainDictionnary.bcfFilter}, StringFormat={}{0} :}"/>
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" Margin="2" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="col1"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1" SharedSizeGroup="marg"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="col2"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1" SharedSizeGroup="marg"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="col3"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Static dictionnaries:MainDictionnary.filterField}" 
                                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                                    Margin="5,2"/>
                            <Line Grid.Column="1"
                                            Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                            Stroke="Gray"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Static dictionnaries:MainDictionnary.filterCondition}"
                                                Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,2"
                                                TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            <Line Grid.Column="3"
                                            Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                            Stroke="Gray"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Static dictionnaries:MainDictionnary.filterValue}"
                                                Grid.Column="4" Margin="5,2"
                                                TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Line Grid.Row="0" Fill="Black" 
                                        X2="{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay ,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                                        Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="50" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="col1"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1" SharedSizeGroup="marg"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="col2"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1" SharedSizeGroup="marg"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="col3"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3" SelectedItem="{Binding Field}"/>
                    <Line Grid.Column="1"
                                    Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                                        Stroke="Gray"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3" SelectedItem="{Binding Condition}"/>
                    <Line Grid.Column="3"
                                    Y2="{Binding ActualHeight, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                                    Stroke="Gray" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="4"  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3"
                                MinWidth="50"
                                Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"/>
                    <Line VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Column="0"
                                    X2="{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                    Stroke="Black"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,20,0">
        <Button Height="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Margin="2" Padding="0"
                Command="{Binding AddFilterCommand}">
            <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Path.Data>M0,5 H10 M5,0 V10</Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Button>
        <Button Height="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Margin="2"
                Command="{Binding RemoveFilterCommand}">
            <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Path.Data>M0,0 H8</Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The visibility of this part is controled by my viewmodel. Until this everything is working nice, but when I add new rows to the array with the + button, I would like the array not to grow but use a ScrollViewer. So in the ItemControl.template is added the scrollViewer.

But I got this result :

[image: The row height is not priority...]

How can I get the scrollviewer to work ?

Comment: scroll viewers work on fixed heights, providing auto as your grid row height just divides the available space in 2, put them on leash, set height or max height

Comment: @Muds thank you, I was hopping for an other solution but I'll do with that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Height` of the second `RowDefinition` to `*`:

```
<RowDefinition Height="*"/>
```

Or set the `Height` property of the `ItemsControl` or `ScrollViewer`.

A `ScrollViewer` must have a constrained height to be able to calculate the scrollable view port.

Comment: Thank you ! can't expected better and simpler =)